# Instead of using ?id=30

Tags: php

and thanks for taking a look to this weird and awkward post.

I have been working on a Cars website for a while (version: 1) wich is pretty basic, now im learning a little bit more about POO so i guess i will be updating it...

I have seen before on a Scripts website that they do this:

Example:

websiteurl.com/scripts/view/300 or websiteurl.com/scripts/view/1761/media/
 or websiteurl.com/scripts/view/1761/comments

Im currently doing this:

mywebsite.com/viewCars.php?id=300 but i would like instead of doing that , doing this:

mywebsite.com/cars/view/300

Thanks, and i hope someone understand my question, forgive me for my bad spelling but english isn't my first language.

Comment: What you need is .htaccess file rules. search for .htaccess generators.

Comment: To be exact look for `url rewriting`

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response ! i found it as url rewriting <3 REALLY THANKS ! seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using apache, soemthiing like this should give you the format you mentioned

```
in your .htaccess file
----------------------

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cars/view/([0-9]+)$ viewCars.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

have you heard about htaccess. Check the documentaion. You can sole your problem by using htaccess and some regular expresion. Here is an example solution for your question.

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

For your solution, you can write following code in your htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cars/view/([0-9]+)$ viewCars.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MVC architecture, you could do something like this:

```
function __construct() {

    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);


    if (empty($url[0])) {
        require 'controllers/index.php';
        $controller = new Index();
        $controller->index();
        return false;
    }

    $file = 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    } else {
        $this->error();
    }

    $controller = new $url[0];
    $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

    // calling methods
    if (isset($url[2])) {
        if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
            $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
        } else {
            $this->error();
        }
    } else {
        if (isset($url[1])) {
            if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                $controller->{$url[1]}();
            } else {
                $this->error();
            }
        } else {
            $controller->index();
        }
    }


}
```